# What event is fired after opening the android app from background?

Tags: android, events, android-studio

I am using android app, i press home button and i open the app again from the launch icon.

Which event is fired?

because when i open the app again, the layout is lost...

[image]

After re open
[image]

here is the code for on create method

**ON CREATE**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              

    INSTANCE = this;

    Constants.initializeConstantsFromResources(this);

    Controller.getInstance().setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));       

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_SHOW_FULL_SCREEN, false)) {          
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_GENERAL_HIDE_TITLE_BARS, true)) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    setProgressBarVisibility(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);                        

    mCircularProgress = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner);

    EventController.getInstance().addDownloadListener(this);                

    mHideToolbarsRunnable = null;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    buildComponents();                

    mViewFlipper.removeAllViews();   

    updateSwitchTabsMethod();
    updateBookmarksDatabaseSource();

    registerPreferenceChangeListener();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.getData() != null) {
        // App first launch from another app.
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(i.getDataString());
    } else {
        // Normal start.
        int currentVersionCode = ApplicationUtils.getApplicationVersionCode(this);
        int savedVersionCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, -1);

        // If currentVersionCode and savedVersionCode are different, the application has been updated.
        if (currentVersionCode != savedVersionCode) {
            // Save current version code.
            Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, currentVersionCode);
            editor.commit();

            // Display changelog dialog.
            Intent changelogIntent = new Intent(this, ChangelogActivity.class);
            startActivity(changelogIntent);
        }




        /*
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_RESTORE_LAST_PAGE, false)) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {               
                String savedUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(Constants.EXTRA_SAVED_URL);
                if (savedUrl != null) {
                    addTab(false);
                    navigateToUrl(savedUrl);
                    lastPageRestored = true;
                }
            }
        }*/

        boolean lastPageRestored = false;
        // gaf - comienzo con la pagina inicial
        String savedUrl = "file:///android_asset/startpage/index.html";
        //String savedUrl = "http://servidor-cade.com";
        //String savedUrl = "http://192.168.1.18:3636";
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(savedUrl);
        lastPageRestored = false;

        //if (!lastPageRestored) {
        //  addTab(true);
        //}
    }

    initializeWebIconDatabase();

    startToolbarsHideRunnable();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up about Activity lifecycle.

You can use `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

Have a look at this doc:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: Any idea why i loose the viewflipper content?

Comment: perhaps you have some code in onCreate that needs to run in onResume because it wont be called ?

Comment: How do you make that layout ? Do you load it dynamically ? Show some code here so we can help